# QCompleter only works every 2nd time in a QGraphicsView

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qgraphicsview

I have a `QLineEdit` with a `QCompleter` inside a `QGraphicsScene`. For some reason, the auto-completions repeatedly appear and disappear every time you press a button. Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Code:

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)

line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter(['123456789', '1234567890'])
line_edit.setCompleter(completer)
scene.addWidget(line_edit)

view.show()
app.exec()
```

This only happens inside a `QGraphicsView`; without the GraphicsView the dropdown works as expected. Why does it disappear and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is that the dropdown list yoinks the keyboard focus from the `QLineEdit`, and then pressing another key closes the dropdown. As a workaround, we can intercept the `keyPressEvent` and move the keyboard focus back to the `QLineEdit`:

```py
class LineEditProxy(QtWidgets.QGraphicsProxyWidget):
    """
    When a QLineEdit has a QCompleter and is inside a QGraphicsView, something
    goes wrong with the keyboard focus, and the dropdown list that displays the
    QCompleter's suggestions disappears on every 2nd key press. This class fixes
    that issue.
    """
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        result = super().keyPressEvent(event)
        self.widget().setFocus()
        return result

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)

line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter(['123456789', '1234567890'])
line_edit.setCompleter(completer)

# Use this instead of `scene.addWidget(line_edit)`
proxy = LineEditProxy()
proxy.setWidget(line_edit)
scene.addItem(proxy)
```